# Control slideToggle() jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, slidetoggle

I have 4 form_header divs and 4 form_body divs. I'm using jQuery slideToggle() to expand the form_body divs by clicking the form headers.

This is a perfect example of what I'm doing:
[jQuery collapsible div](http://roshanbh.com.np/examples/exapandable-panel/)

This is the code I've used:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function(){

        $(".form_body").hide();

        $(".form_header").click(function(){
            $(this).next(".form_body").slideToggle(0);
        });
        });
    </script>
```

What I would like is when I expend one of these divs, and I expand another one the expanded one collapses, so that one can't expand two or more of them at the same time. How can I do that? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As has already been noted it may be easier to use a plugin for this, but alternatively, something like this should do the trick:

```
$(".form_header").click(function() {
   $(".form_body").not($(this).next()).slideUp();
   $(this).next(".form_body").slideToggle(); 
});
```

It hides all the other `.form_body` elements, then toggles the correct one. See an example running [here](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/nBhAA/).

Comment: With this code, all divs are expanded by default. How can I fix that?

Comment: Everything else works though! I just want them to be hidden on page load.

Comment: I already fixed it by putting this first: $(".form_body").hide(); thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You might be better off using [jQuery UI Accordion](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/). The functionality you are after is already built in.

Comment: I don't want to use jQuery theme and customizing it to look like my current theme will take a lot of time. Is it so difficult to do without using this Accordion?